# Ordered statistics of sum of uniform variates

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y,Z \sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$. What will be the distribution of $W = \min(X+Y,Y+Z)$?

I think that first of all I should find out the distributions followed by $X+Y$ and $Y+Z$, and then find out the ordered statistic, but I'm still getting a wrong answer.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not explicitely written, but I guess that $(X,Y,Z)$ is an independent vector, isn't it?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Yes

Comment: "I think that ..." No! You do not have to find the distributions of $X+Y$ and $Y+Z$, and again: no! you do not have to find out the (distribution of) ordered statistics. Fortunately that fuzz is all not needed (see my answer to your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is evident that $W$ takes values in $[0,2]$ so it is enough to find $P(W\leq w)$ or equivalently $P(W>w)$ for $w\in[0,2]$:

$\begin{aligned}P\left(W>w\right) & =\int_{0}^{1}P\left(X+Y>w,Y+Z>w\mid Y=y\right)dy\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}P\left(X>w-y,Z>w-y\mid Y=y\right)dy\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}P\left(X>w-y,Z>w-y\right)dy\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}P\left(X>w-y\right)P\left(Z>w-y\right)dy\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}P\left(X>w-y\right)^{2}dy
\end{aligned}
$

The third equality is based on independence of $Y$ wrt $X$ and $Z$.

The fourth equality is based on independence of $X$ and $Z$.

The fifth equality is based on the fact that $X$ and $Z$ have the same distribution.

Now it is time to discern cases.

If $w\in\left[0,1\right]$ then we proceed with:

$\begin{aligned}P\left(W>w\right) & =\int_{0}^{w}P\left(X>w-y\right)^{2}dy+\int_{w}^{1}P\left(X>w-y\right)^{2}dy\\
 & =\int_{0}^{w}\left(1-w+y\right)^{2}dy+\int_{w}^{1}1dy\\
 & =\left[\frac{1}{3}\left(1-w+y\right)^{3}\right]_{0}^{w}+1-w\\
 & =\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\left(1-w\right)^{3}+1-w\\
 & =1-w^{2}+\frac{1}{3}w^{3}
\end{aligned}
$

If $w\in\left[1,2\right]$ then we proceed with:

$\begin{aligned}P\left(W>w\right) & =\int_{0}^{w-1}P\left(X>w-y\right)^{2}dy+\int_{w-1}^{1}P\left(X>w-y\right)^{2}dy\\
 & =\int_{0}^{w-1}0dy+\int_{w-1}^{1}\left(1-w+y\right)^{2}dy\\
 & =0+\left[\frac{1}{3}\left(1-w+y\right)^{3}\right]_{u-1}^{1}\\
 & =\frac{1}{3}\left(2-w\right)^{2}\\
 & =\frac{4}{3}-\frac{4}{3}w+\frac{1}{3}w^{2}
\end{aligned}
$

Comment: what is $u$? Also, where is the inequality $X+Y \leq Y+Z$ incorporated in the above solution?

Comment: $u$ was a typo and should be $w$ (repaired now). Why $X+Y\leq Y+Z$?? It is about $W=\min(X+Y,Y+Z)$ so that $W>w\iff X+Y>w\wedge Y+Z>w$, right?

Comment: Although your answer is correct, I'm confused about how you arrived at it. I was thinking in the following way- Let $X_1 = X+Y$, and $X_2 = Y+Z$ be the new random variables. Now, $W = \min(X+Y,Y+Z)=\min(X_1,X_2)$. Thus, we are now supposed to find the lowest order statistic. I was hoping that you'll use a similar method, but your solution is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Then if you do it with $W=\min(X_1,X_2)$ how did you intend to proceed? Not also by $\min(X_1,X_2)>w\iff X_1>1\wedge X_2>w$? If so then the method looks a lot like mine and a pre of mine is that I avoid awkward calculation of distribution new random variables $X_1,X_2$. If not then what is your alternative?

Comment: That's where I was stuck. I was assuming that let $X_1 \leq X_2$.
Can you please explain this line-$ \min(X_1,X_2)>w\iff X_1>1\wedge X_2>w$

Comment: Personally I would discourage the use of ordered statistics here. Simply because we do not need them. Feel free to mention what is unclear in my answer.

Comment: Oh you mean ordered statistics $X_{(1)},X_{(2)}$ here and then finding the distribution of $X_{(1)}$. Well, see my former comment.

Comment: can you explain the limits of the integrals?

Comment: In both cases ($w\in[0,1]$ and $w\in[1,2]$) it concerns an integral over interval $[0,1]$. If $w\in[0,1]$ we must discern the cases $y\in[0,w]$ and $y\in[w,1]$. If $w\in[1,2]$ we must discern the cases $y\in[0,w-1]$ and $y\in[w-1,1]$. So in both cases there is summation of two integrals.